# Need to extract text in a C# Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a collection of strings such as `Some song [FEAT. John Doe]` and I'm trying to extract the 'featured' part. It could be identified by one of several different words `"FEAT|FEAT\\.|Featuring"` and may or may not be enclosed by brackets. I'm using a Regex for this and here is what I've got so far:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ExtractFeaturedPerformers()
{
    IEnumerable<string> titles = new string[]
    {
        "abc [FEAT one two] 123",
        "def(FEAT. three'four) 456",
        "ghi Featuring five",
        "jkl"
    };

    // Must be able to use an arbitrary array of words
    var arrayOfWords = new string[] { "FEAT", "FEAT.", "Featuring" };
    string options = string.Join("|", arrayOfWords.Select(s => Regex.Escape(s)));
    var result = new List<string>();

    foreach(string title in titles)
    {
        var _ = Regex.Match(title, $@"(?<=({options})\s*)(.*?)(?=[\]\)]|$)");
        if (_.Success)
            result.Add(_.Value);
    }

    Assert.AreEqual(3, result.Count());
    Assert.IsTrue(result.Contains("one two"));
    Assert.IsTrue(result.Contains("three'four"));
    Assert.IsTrue(result.Contains("five"));
}
```

I have it mostly working but there are two limitations. My main problem is that the second result includes the `.`.

`. three'four`

How can I remove this as part of the Regex so that I can accept an arbitrary `options` string rather than stripping it away later? Dealing with the `.` is my main concern but I would also appreciate suggestions for removing the leading and trailing whitespace from the result so that I don't have to call `Trim()` later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need

```cs
(?:FEAT\.?|Featuring)\s*([^])]*)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3aFEAT%5c.%3f%7cFeaturing%29%5cs*%28%5b%5e%5d%29%5cn%5d*%29&i=abc+%5bFEAT+one+two%5d+123%0d%0adef%28FEAT.+three%27four%29+456%0d%0aghi+Featuring+five%0d%0ajkl)

*Details*

- `(?:FEAT\.?|Featuring)` - `FEAT` and an optional `.` or `Featuring`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace
- `([^])]*)` - *Capturing group 1*: zero or more chars other than `]` and `)`.

You need to amend the C# code to get Group 1 values.

Here is the [full C# demo](https://ideone.com/jReiwq):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> titles = new string[]
        {
            "abc [FEAT one two] 123",
            "def(FEAT. three'four) 456",
            "ghi Featuring five",
            "jkl"
        };

        var keys = new List<string> { "FEAT", "FEAT.", "Featuring" };
        keys = keys.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).ToList();
        var pattern = $@"(?:{string.Join("|", keys.Select(z => Regex.Escape(z)))})\s*([^])]*)";
        Console.WriteLine(pattern);
        
        var result = new List<string>();
        foreach(string title in titles)
        {
            var _ = Regex.Match(title, pattern);
            if (_.Success)
                result.Add(_.Groups[1].Value);
        }
    
        Console.WriteLine( result.Count()); // Assert.AreEqual(3, result.Count());
        Console.WriteLine( result.Contains("one two") ); //Assert.IsTrue(result.Contains("one two"));
        Console.WriteLine( result.Contains("three'four") ); //Assert.IsTrue(result.Contains("three'four"));
        Console.WriteLine( result.Contains("five") ); // Assert.IsTrue(result.Contains("five"));
    }
}
```

The output is

```
(?:Featuring|FEAT.|FEAT)\s*([^])]*)
3
True
True
True
```

Note how the regex pattern is built:

- `var keys = new List<string> { "FEAT", "FEAT.", "Featuring" };` initializes the `keys` string list with the search phrases
- `keys = keys.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).ToList();` - sorts the items in the list by length in the descending order
- `var pattern = $@"(?:{string.Join("|", keys.Select(z => Regex.Escape(z)))})\s*([^])]*)";` - creates the regex pattern by putting the escaped search phrases into a non-capturing group with `|` alternation operator in between, `(?:Featuring|FEAT\.|FEAT)`.

Comment: Why drop the Lookbehind solution though?

Comment: @41686d6564 Because an optional `.` in the lookbehind is troublesome. Since the regex engine searches for matches from left to right, the location before `FEAT` will be found earlier and the dot will still be present in the match. When using a consuming pattern, the optional dot will get consumed and will be absent from the Group 1 value. `(?<=(?:FEAT\.?|Featuring)\s)([^])]*)` might work if there is always a single whitespace after `Feat` part. Capturing mechanism is safer in these situations.

Comment: Ah, I always forget this caveat with Lookbehinds. Thank you, Wiktor. I stand corrected. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Wiktor. It works great for `FEAT`, `FEAT.`, & `Featuring`. The only trouble is, I need to be able to accept an arbitrary string.

Comment: @Connell.O'Donnell Do you mean like `string options = string.Join("|", collectionOfWords.Select(s => Regex.Escape(s)));`?

Comment: @41686d6564 , that's correct. I'll update the question to make it clearer.